# "Cannot create database 'OSystem'" while starting Sonatype Nexus

Tags: repository

While starting Sonatype Nexus, I am getting following error:

> ```
> *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl - Failed transition: NEW -> STARTED
> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot create database 'OSystem'
> 2019-04-16 07:15:28,714+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable - Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OLowDiskSpaceException: Error occurred while executing a write operation to database 'OSystem' due to limited free space on the disk (1121 MB). The database is now working in read-only mode. Please close the database (or stop OrientDB), make room on your hard drive and then reopen the database. The minimal required space is 4096 MB. Required space is now set to 4096MB (you can change it by setting parameter storage.diskCache.diskFreeSpaceLimit) .
>         DB name="OSystem"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no disk space left so the system cannot start.

Minimal system requirements are listed [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/System+Requirements) for NXRM3.  But yes, need at least 4G to even start...don't expect to be able to store much if you are not higher than that.